# FloatImage in folium map is way too big

Tags: python, folium

I want to insert a legend as an image in my map with FloatImage. Last week it worked great, the image was in good quality on the bottom right. I did not change the code and the image now appears huge.

```
import folium

from folium.plugins import FloatImage

m = folium.Map(location=[52.542100, 13.384019], zoom_start=10)

image = ('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d6/Beispiel.png')        
FloatImage(image, bottom=10, left=1).add_to(m)

m
```

Anyone got the same problem?

I have also tried other images and changed the image size, always the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that was introduced in 0.13.0. It’s fixed in the upcoming 0.14.0 release. In the meantime you can work around it by manually setting the ‘width’ argument of FloatImage.

Comment: downgrading folium version to 0.12.1 solved the issue.